# ERLANG - Default Float Size

Tags: erlang, floating-point, integer

Is there any way to prevent a number such as 10000000 being auto converted to a float?

Comment: What do you mean by autoconverted to a float? All integers that I have ever worked with have always stayed integers no matter how big they are.

Comment: Can you show the context where you think this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No integers get autoconverted to float:

Just typing into the erlang shell:

```
1> 10000000.
10000000
2> 1000000000000000000000000000000000.
1000000000000000000000000000000000
3> 1000000000000000000000000000000000 + 1.
1000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: Division with / will autoconvert while div will result in integers.

Answer (score 7):

There are two contexts in which something like autoconversion happens:

1. When comparing numbers for equality (you can use `=:=` to prevent autoconversion):

   ```
   1> 1 == 1.0.
   true
   2> 1 =:= 1.0.
   false
   ```
2. Also, `/` works different to C and similar languages and will always return a float (use `div` for integer division).

But in neither case the size of the numbers matters.